# Probability from multiple trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This questions is from a practice mid-term that I don't have a solution to.

> A monkey in a research lab is given 6 tiles with the letters AAABNN. On each trial the monkey randomly arranges the tiles, and gets a banana if the tiles spell BANANA.
>
> 1. What is the probability of the monkey getting a banana on the 1st trial?
> 2. Let X be the number of bananas the monkey has received after N trials. Give an expression for pX(X).
> 3. How many trials should there be so that the monkey has a 20% chance of getting at least two bananas?

The first part seems simple enough. Just take how many options there are, and it will be 1 over that many.

$$\frac{6!}{3!2!1!} = 60 \therefore P = \frac{1}{60}$$

The second part I'm not exactly sure what is being asked for, and for the vague idea of what it might be (A P.D.F formula), I don't know how to do.

The third part I think my thinking just needs to be corrected. The trials would be independent, so every one would have a probability of $\frac{1}{60}$. And that should mean that every trial is $\frac{1}{60}$, but then in 10 trails, the probability would still be $\frac{1}{60}$, which seems both right and wrong in concept.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't the monkey learn to arrange the tiles so that it would receive a banana?

Comment: @EpicGuy, this is math, not Psychology. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $$\frac{6!}{3!2!1!} = 60 \therefore P = \frac{1}{60}$$

For second, since each trial is independent, after $N$ trials, it's binomial distribution, and 
$$P(X=n)=\binom{N}{n}P^n(1-P)^{N-n}$$

For the third question, after $N$ trials, the monkey receives at least 2 banana has probability, $$Q=1-(1-P)^N-\binom{N}{1}P(1-P)^{N-1}$$
The question then asks you to find the smallest $N$ such that $Q\geq 20\%$

Comment: Can you explain the last formula? Also, it should be 60.

Comment: @David You are right. I forget it's $3!$. Also, for the last equation, probability of getting at least two bananas equals all possible outcome (1) minus the probability of getting no banana and exactly one banana.

Comment: How would I go about solving for N then considering there's an N! in there?

Comment: Is this something you just have to solve by trial and error? Even WolframAlpha didn't come up with a decent answer.